# decimal rounding but keeping it a decimal

Tags: c#

How does one keep it a decmail without converting it as a string. I dont want to have to cahnge it to text as I am using value changed event to trigger a sum

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {        
    clientearningscic.Value = (decimal) _dal.getiandEData(_myuser.id, "clientearningscic") ;
    otherincomeonecic.Text = _dal.getiandEData(_myuser.id, "otherincomethreecic").ToString("n2");

 }
   clientearningscic.ValueChanged += sumEarnings;
```

Any ideas would help me allot

```
private void sumEarnings(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int total = Convert.ToInt16(clientearningscic.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(partnerearningscic.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(incomesupportcic.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(childtaxcreditcic.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(workingtaxcreditcic.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(pensioncic.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(childbenefitcic.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(chidlmaintenancecic.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(nondependantscontributioncic.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(otherincomeonecic.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(otherincometwocic.Text) + Convert.ToInt16(otherincomethreecic.Text);

        lblTotalIcome.Text = total.ToString();

        calcTotal();

}
```

Comment: Don't save it as an `int` but as a `double` instead. Integers only support whole numbers, whereas `double` supports floating point numbers.

Comment: Have you tried Math.Round(), the function gets the value and number of decimals as inputs.

Comment: please accept an answer

Answer (score 2):

Converting the text values to the Int16 datatype will not allow any decimals. Try converting these to double, decimal, or float.

To round the value to a certain number of decimals, use

```
Math.Round(decimal val, # of decimals);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saving it as an integer. Integers support whole numbers from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. But they don't support decimal values.

To use decimal values, you can't use `int` but you can use `float` or `double`.